# HTML SublimeText3 PROBLEM UPLOADING IMAGE

Tags: html, upload

I can't upload an image to the website, I'm writting the address correctly and still, it doesn't show up. I'm doing it from a Mac, but still, it should work!

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

Thank you

```
<img src= "‎⁨‎⁨Imagenesweb/kitty.jpeg" alf="Imagen de un gato" title="Foto 
de gato" width="255" height="500"/>
```

Comment: Without knowing what name the image has or where you put it in relation to the HTML file, it's hard to say what might be going on here.

Comment: Sorry, the name of the image it's the same as in the code "Kitty.jpeg" and the image has been stored in "Imagenesweb", inside the folder with the .html file where the website is in

Comment: Your comment says it's named `Kitty.jpeg` but the code has it named `kitty.jpeg`. Those are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea about this issue but i'm also mac user,

Your code snippet is okay it should be worked but it doesn't then i changed folder name to the "Image" / "image" it works.

Imagenesweb/kitty.jpeg for call this you've a folder with "Imagenesweb" this name.

and inside of this folder you should have this file "kitty.jpeg".

Change folder name to "image" / "Image"  it will work. Maybe there is something related with OSX.